# Microsoft Teams is not accepting my client certificate as part of login

Tags: google-chrome, electron, multi-factor-authentication, microsoft-teams

I have recently started to use the Microsoft Teams desktop app (v0.7.00.3101) on macOS Sierra, and everything was working fine. My company recently switched to using client certificates for authentication (MFA), and the Teams desktop app does not allow me to log in since then.

I have installed the certificate and the respective root certificates on my Mac, and I can log in to https://teams.microsoft.com successfully using Google Chrome. After I type in my email address on the MS login screen, I'm forwarded to my company's login page, and after entering my password there, Chrome shows a dialog to select a certificate. Once I select that, I'm forwarded to the MS Teams site.

When using the Desktop app (which internally calls Chrome, I guess), I get to my company's login page, and enter the password there, but then the app just stays there and does not select the certificate.

The same approach is working just fine for a co-worker. In his case, the MS Teams app selects the certificate automatically and signs him in.

Is there a way in the MS Teams desktop app to find out more about what Chrome is doing and why it's not selecting the certificate?

**UPDATE:**
After some more digging, I found a way to get MS Teams/Electron to spit out additional information:

```
cd /Applications/Microsoft Teams.app/Contents/MacOS

ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true ./Teams
```

This caused logging to show up in the Console, and once it hit the login screen that fails to send the certificate to the server, the following appeared in the log:

```
[47746:0215/104528:ERROR:client_cert_store_mac.cc(98)] CopyCertChain error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "paramErr: error in user parameter list" (-50)
```

This error message is shown several times, I guess once per certificate that it found. From this error message, I found the following bug report - seems to be an open issue that was introduced with macOS Sierra: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=649953

That also explains why this is working for my colleague, since he's still on macOS El Capitan, where this error is not present...

Is there anything I can do to update MS Teams to use the bug fix, or is this something that needs to be reported to the MS Teams team for them to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working fine. I'm currently using macOS 10.12.5 and MS Teams 1.0.00.17151, and the issue is fixed.

When I log in in Teams, a popup dialog appears, showing my certificates, allowing me to select the one I want to use.

Whether this was fixed in a macOS update, or in a Teams update is not clear to me - but the good news is that this is working now.

Sidenote: I had reported this issue on the [Teams UserVoice site](https://aka.ms/microsoftteamsplatformsuggestions) as a bug report, but it was deleted by an administrator, possibly when the bug had been fixed. I did not receive a notification from UserVoice about the deletion, I only noticed it when actively searching for my post.